# How do I disable the FTP service using command prompt or batch?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, windows-10, command-prompt

I am trying to figure out how to disable FTP service using command prompt. I already know the way where you can go to to turn windows features on or off, but I want to use the command prompt for a script I am writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stops the service not permanently

```
@echo off
net stop msftpsvc
goto :eof
```

And this one stops it permanently

```
@echo off
sc config msftpsvc start= disabled
goto :eof
```

Comment: The second one doesn't stop it at all, it simply changes the configuration, to prevent it from running at next start/login.

Comment: This answer is not bad so why it is down voted from 2 to 0?

Comment: Wasif, I'm unable to answer that, _(I didn't downvote your answer)_. Perhaps it was for the reason I gave in my previous comment, where you incorrectly stated that the `SC Config` command stopped it permanently. It doesn't stop it at all. If it is running it will continue to do so until it receives a `Stop` notification. Might I suggest that you try `SC Stop ServiceName` as well as changing the `Start` configuration. It is also important to note that some services may not accept a stop request from the user, so it may be necessary to query its current state and whether it can be stopped first.

Comment: Ok, @Compo, I will improve my later answers